# Same flow for Login and Signup: Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase-authentication

I am using account kit and need to store the number@app.com on firebase. So I tried to do with their email and password flow. 
But the problem I found their is that they have two different flows: one to create user, which is initiated at the time of register- createUserWithEmailAndPassword and other in the login flow, which need to be initiated at the time of login when user is already created -signInUserWithEmailAndPassword.

Is there something like a same create and sign in call, which can figure it out whether it is first time user, so create it or an existing user.

I can have a server check on my end but it brings in delay and multiple call to different system.

Comment: Calling `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` will sign in that user if it is created and fail if a user with that email address already exists.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51443538/how-to-check-whether-a-user-is-authenticated-or-not-in-firebase

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
firebase.auth().fetchProvidersForEmail(email)
    .then(function(providers) {
      if (providers.length > 0 ) {
        // The user has already been registered. Careful though: the
        // following assumes that your users only sign up with email
        // and password. If they can sign up with other providers
        // (Google, Facebook...), you may not be able to do the next
        // call.
        return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email, password);
      } else {
        // No account exists with this email address.
        return firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email, password);
    }).then(function(user) {
      // User is signed in!
    });
```

This will first check for the providers linked to that email address. If the list is not empty, and your users can only sign up with email and password (so no Google sign-in, Facebook login, etc.) then it is guaranteed that the user has already signed up with email and password. In this case, you can sign in the user. If the list is empty, no user exists, and you can create a new user.

Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new account and verify if email is already used, and login it instead.

```js
const auth = firebase.auth();
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(cred => {

}).catch(err => {
    if(err.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(cred => {
            console.log(cred);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err.message);
        })
    } else {
        console.log(err.message);
    };
});
```