# How to check whether a user is authenticated or not in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have a few sign-up methods in my app as shown below:

[image]

Let's revolve the problem around *Google sign-in method*:
What I am doing is that when a user signs in `enteringDataIntoUserNode()` method is called inside `signInWithCredential()` method like:

```
    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    AuthCredential credential = 
           GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);

    //  signing in
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        //  entering default values in the database
                        enteringDataIntoUserNode();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginAndSignupActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                    }

                }
            });
}
```

*enteringDataIntoUserNode()*

```
private void enteringDataIntoUserNode() {
    final String currentUid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    //
    String deviceToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    final String userName = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();
    String imageUrl = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl().toString();
    String userStatus = "Hi there! How is it going?";

    //  inserting data in key-value pair
    usersReference.child(currentUid).child("user_name").setValue(userName);
    usersReference.child(currentUid).child("user_status").setValue(userStatus);
    usersReference.child(currentUid).child("user_image").setValue(imageUrl);
    usersReference.child(currentUid).child("device_token").setValue(deviceToken);

    //  when this last value will be inserted then, making an intent to MainActivity
    usersReference.child(currentUid).child("user_thumb_image").setValue(imageUrl)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Data insertion for the new user is successful ");
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

*enteringDataIntoUserNode()* method is simply passing some default data to the database every time a user signs in. But if a user change its details like image or username etc. and sign out and again sign in through *Google sign in method* then again *enteringDataIntoUserNode()* method will be called and user details would be overwritten with the default ones.

My question is that is there any way to check whether a user is signing in for the first time or not during the *Google sign in* so that in the latter case I can skip calling *enteringDataIntoUserNode()* method and prevent overwriting of data.
Same thing I want to acheive during *Facebook* and *Phone Number* sign in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check if the user logs in for the first time, it's the same thing if you want to check if a user is new. So to solve this, we can simply call the `isNewUser()` method in the `OnCompleteListener.onComplete` callback like this:

```
OnCompleteListener<AuthResult> completeListener = new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            boolean isNewUser = task.getResult().getAdditionalUserInfo().isNewUser();
            if (isNewUser) {
                Log.d("TAG", "The user is new!");
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "The user is not new!");
            }
        }
    }
};
```

For more informations, please see the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo).

Comment: Thanks very much, Alex.

Answer (score 0):

You could check when the account was created with:

```
task.getResult().getUser().getMetadata().getCreationTimestamp()
```

See the [reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUserMetadata.html#getCreationTimestamp()).

But a common approach is also to check if the user already exists in the database [using a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).